SQLParamData returns HY010 after receiving SQL_PARAM_DATA_AVAILABLE
I'm writing C++ application on RHEL7 that is using Miscrosoft ODBC 18 to connect to the MSSQL Server. I followed this steps to set up my environment. Inside the code I'm setting ODBC enironment to use version 3.8 which is required to support SQL_PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT_STREAM and SQL_PARAM_OUTPUT_STREAM parameters.
The problem occurs where I call stored procedure that needs to handle SQL_PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT_STREAM parameter and doesn't return any result set (no SELECT expressions):
CREATE PROCEDURE #TempProc
@inArg varchar(32), @inOutArg varchar(32) OUTPUT
AS
SET @inOutArg = 'Hello from proc'
RETURN 1 

The use case that I have is described in the last row of the table under this link documentation.
After processing all input data by calling SQLParamData and SQLPutData, I receive SQL_PARAM_DATA_AVAILABLE. On the next call to SQLParamData (imediately after receiving SQL_PARAM_DATA_AVAILABLE) I receive HY010 (Function sequence error) status. The first call to SQLParamData that returns SQL_PARAM_DATA_AVAILABLE doesn't give me my custom parameter token that I provided in a call to SQLBindParameter.
Does anyone have any clue what might be the reason. Am I missing something? Should I call something extra after receiving SQL_PARAM_DATA_AVAILABLE that is not mentioned in the documentation?
I tried modified version of the example but essentially the error occurs in the highlighted line:
while ( retcode == SQL_PARAM_DATA_AVAILABLE ) {  
      SQLPOINTER token;   // Output by SQLParamData.  
      SQLLEN cbLeft;     // #bytes remained  
      retcode = SQLParamData(hstmt, &token);  // <-- this line fails
      if ( retcode == SQL_PARAM_DATA_AVAILABLE ) {  
         do {  
            retcode2 = SQLGetData(   
               hstmt,   
               (UWORD) token,          // the value of the token is the ordinal.   
               SQL_C_BINARY,           // The C-type.  
               smallBuffer,            // A small buffer.   
               sizeof(smallBuffer),    // The size of the buffer.  
               &cbLeft);               // How much data we can get.  
         }  
         while ( retcode2 == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO );  
      }  
   }   

